# CSS images not floating

Tags: css

I'm not sure why my images are not being selected by the CSS below. My stylesheet is connected properly and icons show up on the browser.

```
    <footer>
<img class "footerImages" src="images/email.png">
<img class "footerImages" src="images/linkedin.png">
<img class "footerImages" src="images/twitter.png">
<img class "footerImages" src="images/rss.png">
</footer>

.footerImages {
    float: right;
    margin-right: 5px;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Put the equals sign after the class: `class = "footerImages"`.

Answer (score 1):

You are missing the `=` after class. The classes are not assigned to the images.

Answer (score 0):

You have error in your code. Missing `=` right after `class`. Correct code would be-

**HTML**

```
<footer>
    <img class="footerImages" src="images/email.png">
    <img class="footerImages" src="images/linkedin.png">
    <img class="footerImages" src="images/twitter.png">
    <img class="footerImages" src="images/rss.png">
</footer>
```

**CSS**

```
.footerImages {
    float: right;
    margin-right: 5px;
}
```